# Require a tuple with a certain length in python function parameters

Tags: python, parameters, type-hinting

I am writing a function that needs to take in an ordered pair coordinate (represented in a tuple). The problem is that I don't know a way to require it to have exactly two elements in the parameters of the function. Is there a better way to handle this kind of situation (like a better data type to use)? I can't think of anything.

```
def function(coordinate: tuple):
    pass
```

Comment: Specify the types of the tuple elements: `Tuple[int, str]`

Comment: This is mentioned in [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Tuple).

Answer (score 1):

A tuple needs to be of a given length for some non-specific function to be executed properly.

We can check the number of elements in the tuple element by using the `len()` function on it that comes with python directly. Wrapped in a short if condition we can only execute the said function when we have guaranteed that the given tuple has 2 elements in it. Otherwise we may print a short error message for the user.

```
if len(your_tuple) == 2:
    function(your_tuple)
else:
    print("Please enter only 2D coordinates")
```

Comment: Please don't use `tuple` as a variable name.